# Converting a Spinner to a string and to an integer

Tags: java, android, string, integer, type-conversion

I have a spinner working in such a way that, once selected, is converted to a string, which I need in integer form to put back into the sqlite database. Does anyone know any way to do this?

```
@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i,long l) {

    Spinner tqo = (Spinner)adapterView;

    if (tqo.getId() == R.id.toq) {
        TextView mytqo = (TextView)view;
        String tow = (String) mytqo.getText();
    }
```

As you can see above, I need the variable `tow` in integer form so I can use it.

Comment: Did my answer work for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Can you use something like this :

```
   int yourVal = Integer.parseInt(tow);
```

Answer (score 3):

You have a string and want to parse it into an integer? You can use [`Integer.parseInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29). It will take in a string as a parameter and return the integer representation of that string.

Like so:

```
String tow = (String) mytqo.getText();
int towInt = Integer.parseInt(tow);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Integer.parseInt()` to get the integer equivalent of the text input. It's pure java and should work out of the box. So you would want something like this:

```
 int a =  Integer.parseInt(tow);
```